# Latex Titlepage splitted in 2 pages

Tags: pdftex, miktex, titles

I have a problem with a book in Latex. I'm writing a thesis in Latex, using Miktex and TexnikCenter. My problem is that the titlepage is splitted in 2 pages instead being fitted in a single page as should be, spaces are correctly set and it has to fit in a single page, someone can help to find the problem,
Thanks,
Guido

```
%Documento di tipo book in formato a4 con stampa su un solo lato e con capitoli openany%
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,openany]{book}

%usa il package babel italian per la divisione in sillabe%
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

%mostra il numero della sotto sotto sezione e insierisce nell'indice
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

%a seconda del tipo di documento usa un inclusione delle immagini diversa%
\ifx\pdftexversion\undefined
\usepackage[dvips]{graphics}
\else
  \usepackage[pdftex]{graphics}
\fi

%permette di utilizzare le letter accentate%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}

%note numerate a piè di pagina%
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{theorem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
%\graphicspath{ {figures/} }
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
%layout collegamenti --> da togliere per stamparlo!!!
%\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black, urlcolor=blue, citecolor=red}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
%stile del layout%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
% i comandi seguenti impediscono la scrittura in maiuscolo dei nomi dei capitoli e dei paragrafi nelle intestazioni
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{ #1}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}} %scrive anche il numero della sezione
\fancyhf{} % rimuove l'attuale contenuto dell'intestazione
% e del pi\`e di pagina

\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark} %titolo del capitolo a Sx
\fancyfoot[CO,RE]{\thepage} %numero di pagina in basso al centro
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt} % riserva spazio per la linea
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhead{} % ignora, nello stile plain, le intestazioni
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % e la linea
}

%Margini%
%sinistro
\addtolength{\hoffset}{-0.5cm}
%\setlength{\hoffset}{3.5cm} 2.5 + 1 (rilegatura)
%destro%
\addtolength{\textwidth}{2cm}
%\setlength{\textwidth}{15cm} 2.5 = 21(pagina) - 2.5(sinistro) - 15(testo)
%larghezza intestazione%
\addtolength{\headwidth}{2cm}
%\setlength{\headwidth}{15cm}
%alto%
\addtolength{\voffset}{-1cm}
%\setlength{\voffset}{2.5cm}
%basso%
\addtolength{\textheight}{2.8cm}

%divisione in sillabe%
\hyphenation{na-me-spa-ce mec-ca-ni-smi bi-so-gno se-pa-ra-re per-met-ta-no query}

\newcommand{\codice}[1]{\texttt{#1}}

%\title{?}
\author{Serena Cupo}

%interlinea 1,5%
\linespread{1.5}

%inizio numerazione romana%
\frontmatter

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{large}
\begin{centering}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale = 0.8]{logo.JPG}
  \label{fig:roma3}
  \end{figure}
    \vspace{0.4em}
  Università degli Studi \textsl{''Roma Tre''}\\
  \vspace{0.6ex}
  Facoltà di Ingegneria\\
  \vspace{0.6ex}
  Corso di Laurea in Ingegneria Meccanica\\
  \vspace{1.8em}
  \begin{Large} \emph{\textsc{My Thesis My Thesis \\
                    And \\
                    My Thesis My Thesis }}
  \end{Large}
  \vspace{1em}
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
                        \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{}}\\
                                    &        &\\
                            Relatore &       & Correlatore\\
  Prof.\textsl{XXX}     &        & Dott. \textsl{XXX}\\
 \textsl{''Università RomaTre''}        &        &\textsl{''Università La Sapienza''}\\
                                    &&\\
                                    &Laureando&\\                                   
                                    &\textsl{XXX}&\\
                                     &\emph{XXX}&\\          
    \end{tabular}  \vspace{1.5em}
    \begin{center}
  Anno Accademico 2018/2019
  \end{center}
\end{centering}
\end{large}
\end{titlepage}


\newpage

%\include{Ring}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures  
%inizio numerazione normale%
\mainmatter


\end{document}
```

Comment: There is a lot going on in your code. A figure environment is *never* used on a title page.

Answer (score 1):

If you comment this command:

```latex
%interlinea 1,5%
\linespread{1.5}
```

in line `90` of your code, your title page will look as you expect.

To set the **line height** in the *main body* of your document you may try other solutions ([maybe this package would help](https://ctan.org/pkg/setspace)).